# Adding time to a date in PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I an trying to add time to a date in PHP.
Here are my variables and values;

$start_date = 2021-09-02 00:00:00

$start_time = 16:56:00

I want the result to be:

2021-09-02 16:56:00

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$start_time = 16:56:00;
$start_date = 2021-09-02 00:00:00;

//Remove time portion from datetime column
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date));
//Add start time to start date
$combined_date_and_time = $start_date . $start_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variables are already date time type:

```
$result = date_format( date_add($start_date, $start_time), 'Y-m-d H-i-s');
```

If the variables are string type:

```
$result = str_replace('00:00:00', '', $start_date) . $start_time;
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the str_replace example, it worked.